# solving a beehive hidato with backtracking algorithm java

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I hava a table like this:[description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2uO9.png)
i hava to write a java code to take a table like that as input and print the solved table.
solved table must contain a hamiltonian path which starts at 1 position and ends at maximum value(the max value is always given at first ).the only solution i can imagine is back tracking algorithm but i can't  wirte it.
can anybody help me with this?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    List<Integer> w=new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=scan.nextInt();
    int [][] s=new int[2*n-1][2*n-1];
    int [][] v=new int[2*n-1][2*n-1];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s[i]=new int[i+n];
                for(int j=0;j<i+n;j++)
                {
                    s[i][j]=scan.nextInt();
                    if(s[i][j]>0)
                    {
                        w.add(s[i][j]);
                        v[i][j]=1;
                    }
                    else if(s[i][j]==-1)
                        v[i][j]=1;
                    else if(s[i][j]==0)
                        v[i][j]==0;

                }
    }
    for(int i=n;i<2*n-1;i++)
    {
        s[i]=new int[2*n-2-i%n];
        for(int j=0;j<2*n-i%n-2;j++)
        {
            s[i][j]=scan.nextInt();
            if(s[i][j]>0)
                w.add(s[i][j]);
        }
    }
    w.sort(naturalOrder());
}
```

so far i just could take a table as an input

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)